# VB Script Text File Prepend

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, text-files

Anyone know how to quickly prepend (add two new lines of text) to the start of an existing text file using either VB Script or a Bat file? Most elegant solution gets the tick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt", 1)
ReadAllTextFile =   f.ReadAll
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt", 2, True)
f.WriteLine("Blaaa")
f.WriteLine("Blaaaa some more...")
f.Write(ReadAllTextFile)
```

**Source:** [Tek Tips](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1144240&page=1)

Answer (score 5):

Check José Basilios answer for code and reference to the FSO. You will be using that.

*BUT*: I wouldn't go the `ReadAllTextFile = f.ReadAll` route, since that could be a few Gigabytes (who knows?).

*INSTEAD*:

1. open a new file
2. write prepended lines
3. read line by line from old file, writing into new file
4. (close both files)
5. delete old file
6. rename new file -> old file